# useLocation hook fails on page reload when passing userID

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a users page where I pass an individual user obj to a separate User component for an users/:id page

```
      {users.map((user) => (
        <Link
          to={{
            pathname: `users/${user.id}`,
            state: { user }
          }}
        >
```

then reference the user.id as follows in my User component

```
import { useLocation, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { deleteUser, editUser, fetchOneUser } from "../functions/index";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const User = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const user = state.user;

  const history = useHistory();
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({});
  const [editedUser, setEditedUser] = useState({});


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await fetchOneUser(user.id);
      setCurrentUser(res);
      setEditedUser({
        name: res.name,
        age: res.age
      });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [user.id]);
```

this is working fine but I refresh the page I get a typeerror:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')

```
  const user = state.user;
```

what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: The state will be empty when you refresh the page. The solution is refetching the user information by user id. In your case, the current user is holding state value, just adding loading state and then showing the component when the data is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `state` is originated from your `AllUsers` component. So, in your `User` component, you'll only get `state` when you navigate from `AllUsers` to `User` by clicking on the link. When you refresh the page on `User` component, the files for your react app are fetched again from the server but there is no `state` that is passed from `AllUsers` to `User`.
2. To get the `userID` from `params`, `useParams` is the hook you need. Since `params` are reflected in URL as well, there will be no loss of `param` upon refresh. In your `User` component,

```
// imports
import { useLocation, useHistory, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
...
// Component
const User = () => {
  /**
   * Provide the param name you mentioned in your Route
   */
  const { userID } = useParams();
  // Other component logic
};
```